# Accessing ORACLE table from QGIS gives TNS-12545 error?

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms

I have to access one ORACLE tab from QGIS but it does not work.

From Instantclient_12_1 the connection and parameters are ok, while from QGIS we always get TNS-12545 error.

ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN var are setted. But from trace log we noticed that the QGIS client seems to be 11_2. 
Maybe there is a different client in QGIS dir? And this client does not know our env var?

I don't know how to start to search solutions.